# dynamic variable with require

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have a doubt if I read a JSON file with "require" and this JSON file is updated also changes the variable where it is set in the code?

this is an example - this is the constantly updated json file

```
context = {
id: 45121521541, //changing value
name: node,
status: completed,
}
```

and I get the values of this JSON through this code

```
var context = require ('./ context.json')
```

the code will update the json constantly and the data will change, and while the code is active I will get the values of the JSON by means of the 'require', that is possible, or the require will not allow me?

Comment: Not possible.... You would need to write something that polls the file and grabs the content

Comment: are you looking for a real-time data pull?

Comment: If you are then you will have to stream the real-time data that ypu are getting.

Comment: if I want to extract data in real time, while the code is running

Comment: in which way then can I read json files in real time

Comment: Use `setInterval()` to read the file periodically.

Comment: This won't work with `require()` because it will cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`fs.readFileSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) to do this and not `require()` - when you use require the first time it will fetch it into the the [modules require cache](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_cache) and subsequent calls will be loaded from from there so you won't see timely updates. If you delete key from the `require.cache` it will also a trigger a reload, but overall will be less efficient than just reading the file.

Including `fs.readFileSync()` will synchronously read the file contents (blocking) each time it is executed. You can combine with your own caching/etc to make this more efficient. If you can do this asynchronously then using [`fs.readFile()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback) is preferable as it is non-blocking.

```
const fs = require('fs');

// your code

// load the file contents synchronously
const context = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./context.json')); 

// load the file contents asynchronously
fs.readFile('./context.json', (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw new Error(err);
  const context = JSON.parse(data);
});

// load the file contents asynchronously with promises
const context = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  fs.readFile('./context.json', (err, data) => {
    if (err) return reject(err);
    return resolve(JSON.parse(data));
  });
});
```

If you want to delete from the `require.cache` you can do it like so.

```
// delete from require.cache and reload, this is less efficient...
// ...unless you want the caching
delete require.cache['/full/path/to/context.json'];
const context = require('./context.json');
```